# Convert PHP Array to String?

Tags: php, arrays, string, wordpress, loops

I'm working with this PHP Array and I'm trying to convert it into a string:

```
$args=shortcode_atts( array(
    'setting' => 'value',
    'setting' => 'value',
    'setting' => 'value',
), $atts);
```

The result should look like this:

```
' "setting":"value","setting":"value" '
```

I'm not sure how to loop through this? I've also noticed a lot of docs online that include the comma at the end of the last array item - is this ok or should I be in the habit of not including the comma?

Comment: If you put a little effort into a more appropriate response I'd say thanks, without the douche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for json encoded data:

```
$json = json_encode($args);
```